# I'm struggling to make the function work on my code. I'm missing the part where i want to print the letter grade

Tags: python

Write a program that asks the user to enter five test scores.

Assume valid scores will be entered and each number will be entered separately, i.e. you will need 5 variables. The program should display a letter grade for each score and the average test score. Write the following functions in the program:

`main` - asks the user to enter five test scores separately, placing them into five float variables. main should then call showScores 5 times passing one of each of the scores each time. When returned from showScores, main should then call calcAverage passing it the 5 scores.

`showScores` – receives a single score and prints the score to the console (without starting a new line) and sends the score just printed to printLetterGrade which will print a letter grade on the same line.

`printLetterGrade` - accepts a single number as an argument and displays a letter grade for the score
based on the following grading scale:

```
Score Letter Grade
90-100 A
80-89 B
70-79 C
60-69 D
Below 60 F
```

 calcAverage - receives the 5 scores as arguments and displays the average of the scores, along with a letter grade equivalent to that average (take advantage of the function printLetterGrade to display the letter by passing it the calculated average).

Here is a sample run of the program:

```
Enter grade 1: 65
Enter grade 2: 80
Enter grade 3: 90
Enter grade 4: 71
Enter grade 5: 85
65 is D
80 is B
90 is A
71 is C
85 is B
The average is: 78.2 which is C
```

this is what i did so far but im struggling on some parts so that i get the output shown. here's what i have done so far.

```
def main():
    grade1 = float(input("Enter grade 1:"))
    grade2 = float(input("Enter grade 2:"))
    grade3 = float(input("Enter grade 3:"))
    grade4 = float(input("Enter grade 4:"))
    grade5 = float(input("Enter grade 5:"))
    showScores(grade1, grade2, grade3, grade4, grade5)
    calcAverage(grade1, grade2, grade3, grade4, grade5)

def showScores(grade1, grade2, grade3, grade4, grade5):
    print(grade1)printLetterGrade
    print(grade2)printLetterGrade
    print(grade3)printLetterGrade
    print(grade4)printLetterGrade
    print(grade5)printLetterGrade

def printLetterGrade(showScores):
    if(grade < 60):
        return printLetterGrade == "F"
    elif(grade < 70):
        return printLetterGrade == "D"
    elif(grade < 80):
        return  printLetterGrade == "C"
    elif(grade < 90):
        return  printLetterGrade == "B"
    elif(grade < 101):
        return printLetterGrade == "A"
    return printLetterGrade


def calcAverage(grade1, grade2, grade3, grade4, grade5):
    average = (grade1 + grade2 + grade3 + grade4 + grade5)/ 5
    print("The average is {}".format(average))

main()
```

Comment: Please format your question so that it's easier to read

Comment: @ScottMcC do you think you will be able to help ASAP?

Comment: What is your problem? The output looks correct?

Comment: @ScottMcC The problem I'm having is trying to display the grade like this: 65 is D
80 is B
90 is A
71 is C
85 is B
The average is: 78.2 which is C

Comment: @ lincr thank you for the editing part and i like it. I'm new to this so it might take sometime getting used to it. Are you able to help me with the last past

Comment: No problems at all. If you're happy with my answer, if you can mark it as correct that would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to adjust your `showScores` and `printLetterGrade` functions as follows:

```py
def showScores(grade1, grade2, grade3, grade4, grade5):
    print("{} is {}".format(grade1, printLetterGrade(grade1)))
    print("{} is {}".format(grade2, printLetterGrade(grade2)))
    print("{} is {}".format(grade3, printLetterGrade(grade3)))
    print("{} is {}".format(grade4, printLetterGrade(grade4)))
    print("{} is {}".format(grade5, printLetterGrade(grade5)))


def printLetterGrade(grade):
    if (grade < 60):
        printLetterGrade = "F"
    elif (grade < 70):
        printLetterGrade ="D"
    elif (grade < 80):
        printLetterGrade = "C"
    elif (grade < 90):
        printLetterGrade = "B"
    elif (grade < 101):
        printLetterGrade = "A"
    return printLetterGrade
```